# building angularJS filter

Tags: angularjs, filter

I'm trying to filter items by field when check is actived buy I get an error.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterActive">
<input type="text" ng-model="reftext"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="nametext"/>


<tr ng-repeat="car in cars.items | togglableFilter:{reference:reftext, name:nametext}:filterActive">

</tr>


.filter('togglableFilter',[function(){
    return function(input, filterText, isFilterActive){

      if(!angular.isDefined(isFilterActive) || !isFilterActive) return input;
      var ret = input;
      var col = [];
      var isDefined = false;

      var key = Object.keys(filterText);

      for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {

        if(angular.isDefined(filterText[key[i]])) {
          isDefined = true;
          angular.forEach(input, function (v) {
            if (v[key[i]].indexOf(filterText[key[i]]) !== -1) {
              col.push(v);
            }
          });
        }
      }

      if (isDefined) return col; else return input;
    }
  }]);
```

Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=car%20in%20cars.items%20%7C%20togglableFilter%3A%7Breference%3Areftext%2C

Comment: The error is telling you to look at this: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=car%20in%20cars.items%20%7C%20togglableFilter:%7Breference:reftext, It would seem that your filter is returning multiple references to the same items.

Comment: `cars.items` has duplicate entries in it so angular is not able to associate a unique key with the DOM element created.if you see the error details in the URL given above you can see that the solution is to use track by $index.

Answer (score 0):

`cars.items` has duplicate entries in it so angular is not able to associate a unique key with the DOM element created.if you see the error details in the URL given above you can see that the solution is to use `track by $index` so that using the `$index` unique value angularJS can track the association between models and DOM

```
 <tr ng-repeat="car in cars.items  track by $index | togglableFilter:{reference:reftext, name:nametext}:filterActive">
```

if you have some difficulty in filtering the data try using

```
 <tr ng-repeat="car in cars.items   | togglableFilter:{reference:reftext, name:nametext}:filterActive track by $index">
```

Comment: If i add the next line <tr ng-repeat="car in cars.items   | togglableFilter:{reference:reftext, name:nametext}:filterActive track by $index"> duplicate cars info when I filter with both filters

Comment: @AgustínCastro what are you trying to do with that filter?

Comment: filter by column when checkbox is actived. I have a lot of input that you can filter by property

Comment: duplicate the result numers when I filter with two o more inputs. for example, if i have two result and i try to filter with two inputs i will get 4 results. but, i i try to filter with one inputs i will get two